# Datatable sorting is not working c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i have a group of values like below pattern

---

> name:   color:  percentage:

i need to sort this data in desc order of percentage

now i am using data-table DefaultView sort  method

```
//declare columns
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("name");
dt.Columns.Add("color");
dt.Columns.Add("percentage");

//adding rows
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["name"]="a";
dr["color"]="red";
dr["percentage"]="10.1";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);

//sorting
dt.DefaultView.Sort="percentage desc";
```

the problem is coming when the same number [percentage] is repeating more times
any idea where is the error?

Comment: If the percentage column is a string, it will sort it as a string and not a percentage value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this code:

```
dt.Columns.Add("percentage");
```

to this:

```
dt.Columns.Add("percentage", typeof(double));
```

Answer (score 1):

As multiple people have pointed out, because you added the percentage as a string ("10.1") it's going to be sorted as a string.  That means, since you're sorting in descending order, that "2" will appear above "10.1" in your sort.  That's because string values are compared character by character, and "2" comes before "1" in a descending alphabetic sort.

Is that the problem you are talking about?  If so, either of the other proposed solutions will work for you.

You also said "the problem is coming when the same number [percentage] is repeating more times"  If you want a secondary sort column, which affects the order of records with the same primary sort column value (`percentage`), you have to specify one:

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort="percentage desc, name asc, color asc";
```